# Connect Python IDE to Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, data-science, spyder

Is there a way for me to work on the environment like Python IDE (such as Spyder) while leveraging the power of GPU in a compute engine? Google has data lab but that is a Jupyter Notebook environment, which is not ideal for code development. I would like to be in an environment where I can debug easily and have a good variable explorer. I would appreciate it if anyone knows a solution to this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio Code you can get a set up similar as you say: with the SSH Remote extension, you can connect VS Code from your PC to a GCP VM and run the workload powered by it. VS Code works in this set up as almost an IDE (actually it is a code editor).
Download and install VS Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/download). Install the SSH Remote extension (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh). Install Google SDK and log in your GCP account
`gcloud init` can be enough). Then on the Power Shell or CMD or Google Cloud SDK run: `gcloud compute shh-config`, and all the started VMs will appear listed and ready to connect through SSH Remote extension.
If you have not a lot of firewall rules closed and security issues.
Hope it works it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine) describing the steps to set a remote desktop on a Compute Engine instance

You can also manually use the GUI of a ubuntu VM or use the Remote Desktop that comes by default with the Windows Server desktop experience images to install your IDE

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris! I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/introducing-cloud-shell-editor,  Cloud Shell Editor, an IDE with many GCP tools built-in running on a pre-provisioned cloud instance.
Direct link is http://ide.cloud.google.com/ - make sure you have Google Cloud account.